Anime Movie with soldiers, a giant god and violent scenes
I'm looking for a Animated Movie or I saw once on the TV late at night when I was young (We're talking like 10 or 15 years ago). It was set in the middle ages and at first I thought it was a cartoon, but there was no way it could have been for kids. Way too violent. There are certain scenes I can remember but cant ever remember the name. I have been dying to know the name of it and see it once more ever since. So anyway I'll start off by describing some scenes:
I'm sure it was about a war because mostly I remember the battle scenes.

I Remember there was like some God who fought for the good side and was able to change his size I think. One minute he was a little bigger than the soldiers, the next he's big enough to walk through the ocean. In this one scene he basically walks through the water to go fight the bad side. So they win the war shortly after.
The bad side shit themselves because they're like "Holy f**k, they got a giant on their side, that's not fair" (Not a direct quote, lol). They decide to make peace with the other army, but hatch up a plan to kill them. They plan to hide some of their soldiers in sacks inside a barn (not sure if it was a barn or not) and later ambush them. One of the good guys discovers this plan. He inspects the barn and discovers the soldiers hiding inside the sacks. He literally crushes their skulls with his bare hands one by one whilst they're inside the sacks and unaware.
Later on whilst they're all celebrating in the barn, the good and the bad, the Hero (who crushed the soldiers skulls) is obviously furious. I remember a specific part where a toddler is roaming around the soldiers and being hugged and stuff, the hero asks why he is not being hugged. The toddler walks over to him, the hero picks him up and literally throws the kid in the bonfire. At this point, all hell breaks loose and the two sides go at it.
After a brief battle, heads being cut off and all kinds of sick stuff, the God gets poisoned in the knee by one of the enemies spears. He later dies but beforehand asks his fellow soldier to take his head (can't remember why). Now the Hero is fighting away and I remember this one part that ends the battle is where he pushes this giant cauldron or something over and wipes out everyone including himself thus ending the battle.

This is everything I can remember. I have searched for this film for years and no success. no hints, no nothing. I've typed in searches some of the scenes to the point of great detail and its coming up "wtf" lol. This movie just blew my mind as a kid and had no idea what the hell it was. There was so much blood and decapitations, I had no idea cartoons were aloud to do this. This was way before I discovered Manga. The thing is, this movie wasn't really as gory as manga, it was more like movies such as Princess Mononoke, Watership Down, or this animated version of Macbeth I also once saw as a kid which didn't really have a lot of blood and seemed like it was meant for children until it showed Macbeth's death by his head being cut off. I'm really hoping someone has more of an idea than I do. Maybe know the best places to look for these kind of films or just have a general idea of what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Huh. I think I recognize the story, but didn't know this was also a movie. I'll look it up.

Sounds like Y Mabinogi (AKA Otherworld) from 2003 which is based on Welsh myth. The film is currently available in its entirety on Youtube. Around 46:30, you can see the toddler thrown into the bonfire in the barn and then a soldier whose head was bashed in released from the sack he was hiding in; around 50:40 is when the cauldron (which revives the dead) explodes; and the giant with the ankle poisoned by a spear is on 52:10. And here's a still from the film with the soldiers carrying his head: 


Awww man your a genius! Cant believe i got to see this once again. It just blew my mind as a kid with all its violence and gore lol I just remember seeing this as some movie me and my brother were flipping through the channels late at night. Must have been like 2 in the morning (Very late for me in 2003). Its interesting that i mentioned that i saw the animated version of Macbeth around the same time i saw this movie because after a little research, i found out it was the same makers. How the hell did you find this? lol I honestly thought this would have been a challenge! Big thanks Walt!

Glad you found it. I recognized some bits of the original myth from your description, so the rest was easy. Don't forget to close the question by clicking on the V sign.
